# How to send mail to group contacts in Gmail without revealing their email ids?

Tags: gmail

How to send mail to all contacts in Gmail but I don't want to send the contact details to all the persons.

For Example

When I send a mail to all contacts by group its possible to send. But the contact details of those who are in my group are sent together with the mail.

So I want to send one mail to all the person but its should one by one automatically so that nobody can see my contacts

Answer (score 5):

Click on "Add BCC". Paste the email ids from to: field to the bcc field.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As Sathya correctly suggests, BCC is an easy way to send to many people without them all knowing who it was sent to. You can also put a group in the BCC field and gmail automatically expands it to all the members of the group and they won't see who else got the email. A common practice when using BCC is to set the TO field to your own address.

An alternative is to use mail merge, where each person gets an individualized email directly to him or her. Here's a link to a tutorial on doing that with gmail: http://www.labnol.org/software/mail-merge-with-gmail/13289/